# Can a WinRT app continue to run while Screen Off?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Can a WinRT app continue to run while Screen Off?

I know that a WinRT application can create a Background Task that periodically executes even when the application is not running. Handy, but not what I am asking. What I am asking is, when the user clicks the power button and invokes Connected Standby, is there anything an app can do to remain active. Can it ask for some special capability?

Example - in Windows Phone there is a handy *Running and Walking* app that keeps track of "where you are" while it is running - then tallies your distances, etc. Even when the screen is off! Turn the screen on and the "where was I" map is up-to-date. Is this type of application possible in WinRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into the same thing recently, and unfortunately it seems that what you want to do isn't possible with WinRT.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Background task to simulate what you are trying to achieve. When the user starts the app again, you could have the info populated to the latest data by looking at the store where the background process updated. Just a thought.

Comment: Background tasks execute every 2 hours (for 1CPU sec) unless the user elevates them to Lock Screen apps, but then only every 15 minutes. See how this is not the same? Good question though.